# Can not display text certain millisecond when mp3/aac play over 1 minute

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-mediaplayer

I create App like-karaoke. But , When my app playing mp3/aac over 1 minute. These text i created is not display. However setText(); under 1 minute is display normally. How can i fix that. I must send teacher tomorrow. Code's be simple. Thank you very much.

```
public class Okkaraoke extends Activity implements MediaPlayerControl,OnClickListener {
private MediaController mMediaController;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public static TextView  subtitles2,subtitles21;


@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.myapp2);


    subtitles2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subs2);
    subtitles21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subs21);


    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaController = new MediaController(this)

    mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(Okekaraoke.this);
    mMediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.AudioView2));
    mMediaController.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Next button clicked
            Intent intent = new Intent(Okkarake.this, Show1.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }, new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Previous button clicked
            Intent intent = new Intent(Okkaraoke.this, Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri
                .parse("android.resource://com.app.suadmon/raw/sorry"));
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            final int currentPos = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            if (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < 28715) {
                subtitles2.setText("Let's start");
                subtitles21.setText("...................");
            }else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 33134) {
                subtitles2.setText("Oh my god");
                subtitles21.setText("Text Displaying");
            }else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < 39811) {
                subtitles2.setText("function is green");
                subtitles21.setText("Text Displaying");
            }else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 44294) {
                subtitles2.setText("Working..");
                subtitles21.setText("Text Displaying");
            }else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 50940) {
                subtitles2.setText("Normally");
                subtitles21.setText("Text Displaying");
            }else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 55387) { 
                subtitles2.setText("Text can show normally");
                subtitles21.setText("Text Displaying");
            }else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 103807) {
                subtitles2.setText("Working");
                subtitles21.setText("Text Displaying");
            }else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()<108173) {
                subtitles2.setText("Text is not show up from here !");
                subtitles21.setText("Text's not Display");
            } else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 112646) {
                subtitles2.setText("All text from here can't show");
                subtitles21.setText("Text's not Display");
            } else if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 119555) {
                subtitles2.setText("TextView din't show up");
                subtitles21.setText("Text's not Display");
            } else if (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 130356) {
                subtitles2.setText("..................");
                subtitles21.setText("Text's not Display");
            } else if (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 138812) {
                subtitles2.setText("************");
                subtitles21.setText("Text's not Display");
            } else if (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()< 147369) {
                subtitles2.setText("Text's not Display");
                subtitles21.setText("*************");           
            }

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1);
        }
    };
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mMediaController.show(0);
                    // mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent newAc = new Intent(Okkaraoke.this, Show.class);
            startActivity(newAc);
        }
    });
}
```

I have music 03.45 minute. In handleMassege(). 
I try final int/long sPos = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); too. But, it's not work. setText is same as code above. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've not done any android development so I'm only guessing... what does [`getDuration()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration()) return? Are you sure the track is the correct length?

Comment: thank. getDuration is correct. If i try to long. It will be show "change return statement to int" or some words like this.

Comment: Yes, `.getCurrentPosition()` returns an int. I guess I could be because you are asking for the curent position many times that is causing a problem. You have correctly copied the current position into a variable with `final int currentPos = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();`. You can make the code more efficient but just using `currentPos` in your if/else statements, rather than calling mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() many times.